# jquery variable in selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want something like:

```
var user_name = $(".hidden_user_name").text();
$("a[name="+ user_name +"]").doStuff()...
```

This works:

```
$("a[name=joe123]").doStuff()...
```

EDIT:

The problem is clearly in that the user_name variable isn't set when the selector fires. How can I fix that?

Comment: The two are identical. There's another issue. Is this your actual code? Or are you assigning the variable from some other source than a string literal?

Comment: 1 accepted answer out of 11 questions is not good for your reputation.

Comment: Also, are you certain that the variable is in the proper scope when you use it? Or has the variable been assigned its value when you use it? Things can easily get out of order if the value is coming from an AJAX call.

Comment: Okay, you're right. 

The issue is that I'm grabbing the user name from a hidden div on the page like so...

var user_login = $.trim($(".user_login").text());
$("a[name="+user_login+"]").text("That's you!").attr("href", "/home");

why isn't that working though?

Comment: should I / how would I move it into a callback so it doesn't fire the selector until the variable is defined?

Comment: @Michael - As long as you are not getting the value via AJAX, or some other asynchronous method, it should work. I see that you're trimming the value, so that's not the issue. Have you tried logging the value to make sure it is correct? `console.log(user_login)` or `alert(user_login)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work. If you're not using some sort of asynchronous method of getting the value (like AJAX), then the second line won't execute until the first is complete.

What type of element is `.hidden_user_name`? If it is an `<input>` and you're trying to get the value of the input, you would do this instead:

```
var user_name = $(".hidden_user_name").val();
```

Or if there's more than one `.hidden_user_name`, you will only get the value of the first that is matched.

Try logging `user_name` before you utilize it to see if it is the value you expected.

```
console.log(user_name);
```

or

```
alert(user_name);
```